# How to execute uWSGI with bash script and display warning if terminal window is closed?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm currently working on a web project on uWSGI, it's quite a chore to keep typing the same command in the terminal everytime I want to start up uWSGI, so I made an executable script that will automatically run the process when I execute it.

It works, but the problem is, normally when I run uWSGI from the terminal manually (by typing in the commands), when I try to close the terminal window while the process is still running, it will prompt me if I want to terminate the process before closing the terminal.
However, the terminal window that appears after I ran the executable script from GUI will not warn me when I accidentally close the window, and as a result the process will still be running in the background.

How can I make the script such that it will display a warning like it normally will when I try to close the terminal window when the process is still running?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following line at the end of your script:

```
$SHELL
```

Comment: thank you very much for helping. I guess there's no way to do it.. the terminal window for the uwsgi that appears will still close without warning when I click on close, and the process still runs in the background, $SHELL only make the window prompt a warning after I end the uwsgi process by pressing Control+C, when the process is still running, no warning will appear when the window is closed.

Comment: @csharpnewbie It's normal as long as the process is running in background. So it no longer has something to do with the terminal. So, if you close the terminal or if you don't close it, you don't affect with nothing the process that running in background. Or make it to not run in background if you prefer to be asked...

Comment: oh. then there's no way to tie the process with the terminal such that it will display warning when the terminal window is to be closed? or to run the process in the foreground and not background? so that the process started by the terminal will terminate when the terminal window is closed?

Comment: @csharpnewbie As I said, make it to not run in background if you prefer to be asked...